# Bootstrap Modal Pop up not firing

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2012

So I am working a web project and hoping to use Bootstrap Modal Pop up. I implemented the codes but unfortunately my modal wont fire. I am using Visual Studio 2012 by the way.

I have included the following:

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Here is my trigger for the modal:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddEvent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Add Event" />
```

And here is my modal:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>

   <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where are you triggering the modal?

Comment: i trigger my modal with button. <asp:Button ID="btnAddEvent" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-default" runat="server" Text="Add Event" />

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap CSS as well?

Comment: yes i did. but it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

include the jQuery script before the bootstrap.js script file for the plugin to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
jquery/bootstrap.js

typo error 'jquery' folder or 'js' folder

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/3v2zg/732/)

Comment: thank you but i did that already and i did not get any response from the modal.

Comment: apparently it did not work. is there another java script in order to call out bootstrap modal?

Comment: which version you are using?

Comment: i am using this theme for the implementation of my project http://bootswatch.com/cyborg/#

Comment: Free Cyborg theme(only CSS) from bootswatch.com is Based on Twitter Bootstrap Version 3.1.1
Make sure you are using Bootstrap Version 3.1.1

Comment: yes i am using version 3.1.1, i really don't know what is wrong here

Comment: <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>

Is it jquery/bootstrap.js or js/bootstrap.js ?

Comment: this what i included.  <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: you made a folder named 'jquery' to store js files? or its just a typo?

Comment: i made i folder for all of my jquery and style sheets. is that a bad practice?

Comment: not exactly but it is always preferred to have a static files folder as : static-->js, css, images etc. this helps in proper management of the assests

Comment: i see, if that is the case, then why my modal isn't firing from trigger? i downloaded bootstrap from nuget and included it to my project. and still not working. this also happens on my dropdown. any suggestions?

Comment: can you please post your project directory structure?

Comment: i'm sorry i dont have enough reputation to post that and i am new at this forum.

Comment: i tried a different approach. i used ajax to call out modal pop up and i used the bootstrap css to design the content. although the show animation is not like in bootstrap. but for the mean time this will do. thank @Gaurav for the help.